# Included Ubuntu OS variable inside apache env vars not working

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

Running application LAMP..
I've declared variable at OS level, inside

> /etc/environment

like this,

> PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
>
> APPLICATION_ENV=dev
>
> SERVERID=1

I'm using these variable in PHP, using function `getenv('APPLICATION_ENV')`. I need these variable accessible via command line, that's why added as OS environment variable.

And to make accessible via Apache,  included '/etc/environment' inside Apache envvars

> #Load all the system environment variables
>
> . /etc/environment

But, it variable 'APPLICATION_ENV' not getting it's value from Apache.

Answer (score 1):

try this,
in apache env fils set daynamic varibale

`/etc/apache2/envvars` **or** `nano /etc/apache2/envvars`

```
export APPLICATION_ENV=${APPLICATION_ENV}
```

`${APPLICATION_ENV}` is your os environment variable

for more info please read this:
https://medium.com/@william.b/setting-dynamic-environmental-variables-in-apache-from-the-os-1d5c1e2e9e6c

i hope help you

Comment: thanks for sharing link.. I tried all 3 method, but no luck.